# Text on the left and image on the right on titlepage

Tags: graphics, titles, minipage

I am trying to make a title page such that there is text on the top left and the university logo on the right. This is what I mean:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \textsc{University Name\\Faculty Name\\Departament Of Electronic Enginnering}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Imagenes/Logo_puj}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
    \centering
    \Large\textbf{BEAUTIFUL TITLE}\\ \textsc{Document}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}


\vfill


\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \textsc{My Name}\medskip\\  
    \textsc{Dirigido por:\\AF, Ph.D.\\JA, Ph.D.}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

\begin{center}
    \textsc{Bogotá - Colombia}\\2021
\end{center} \end{titlepage}
```

Which gives:

[image]

How can I make the top align? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `\vspace{0pt}` at the beginning of first two minipages.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to add `\vspace{0pt}` at the beginning of the minipages as I stated in the comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \textsc{University Name\\Faculty Name\\Departament Of Electronic Enginnering}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Imagenes/Logo_puj}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
    \centering
    \Large\textbf{BEAUTIFUL TITLE}\\ \textsc{Document}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}


\vfill


\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \textsc{My Name}\medskip\\  
    \textsc{Dirigido por:\\AF, Ph.D.\\JA, Ph.D.}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

\begin{center}
    \textsc{Bogotá - Colombia}\\2021
\end{center} \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]